# Spring Boot compatibility issues when upgrading to new libraries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am in the process of upgrading a Spring Boot application to support Micrometer and Actuator monitoring. I have upgraded the Spring libraries to newer versions, and I have refactored the code accordingly (you can see before and after code samples later in in this question). I could run the application successfully before; when I try to do so now, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-20 14:14:59.302 ERROR 29703 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:143) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.openbet.realitycheck.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:210) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

The below screenshot describes the library versions that were previously used:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMCYl.png)

These are the upgraded libraries that I am using now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwlH7.png)

Some before-and-after code samples:

Before:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, IntegrationTestConfiguration.class})
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port=0")
```

After:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, IntegrationTestConfiguration.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Before:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = UnitTestConfiguration.class)
```

After:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = UnitTestConfiguration.class)
```

Here is my starter class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Change the default config name to xxxxxxxxxxxx.
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties(Collections.singletonMap("spring.config.name", "xxxxxxxxxxxx"))
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

When I specify that this is not a Web Application...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Change the default config name to xxxxxxxxxxxx.
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
            .properties(Collections.singletonMap("spring.config.name", "xxxxxxxxxxxx"))
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

...I receive a different set of error messages:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field customerPrefRepository in com.corpname.appname.core.services.CustomerPrefServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.corpname.appname.core.repositories.CustomerPrefRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.corpname.appname.core.repositories.CustomerPrefRepository' in your configuration.
```

As this *is* a web-based application, I don't know of how much use this last bit for information would be.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrading? Did you update the Spring Boot Parent dependency? How does your pomm.xml look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli By 'upgrading', I mean replacing the .jar files for the relevant Spring libraries in Maven with newer versions, as in the screenshots I have included in the question. There are several pom.xml files in the project, as I am working with several smaller projects at once, and I have specified that they must load the newer versions of these libraries.

Comment: Maven has an unfortunate habit of sometimes corrupting jar files when it downloads them. One explanation for the behaviour that you're seeing is that one or more jars from the new version of Tomcat introduced by your Spring Boot upgrade was corrupted when Maven downloaded it. It would be worth purging your local Maven cache and running the build again to see if that helps.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for your advice. I would be grateful if you could provide me with guidance on how to purge and rebuild my local Maven cache.

Comment: I have just tried `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`, and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson If there is really a problem with corrupted jar's during download you have  to use checksums details https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ apart from that it does not look like a problem with corrupted jar's...

Comment: @khmarbaise It looks exactly like a problem with a corrupted jar to me. The app is behaving as if Tomcat is not on the classpath when it should be there transitively via `spring-boot-starter-web`. A common cause of that is jar corruption.

Comment: @SamM Can you update your question with your complete pom.xml? It would also be useful if you could start your app with the `--debug` command-line argument and share the condition evaluation report that it outputs. That should help us to see why the web server hasn’t been auto-configured.

Comment: The problem looks like this: `repositories.CustomerPrefRepository' that could not be found.` ...

Comment: @SamM were you able to solve this issue? I have the same behavior when adding Spring Boot Actuator on version 2.6.7 :(